# Content-Length calculation on api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I have error coming in regarding calculate the content length can any one help me:

```
{ 
  message: 'Bad Request: Bad multipart message parameter',
  status: 400
}

{
  message: "Bad Request: Bad multipart message parameter",
  status: 400
}
mms-orders-functions.js:1832
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that error is related to the Content-Length value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.